# Echo array values which requested with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send with ajax the values of the buttons the user have clicked. After the user clicked a button the ajax should send a request with the updated array values. If I run `var_dump($buttons);` I get `NULL`. Before that I added `$buttons = $_POST['buttons'];` to get the array, but it wont work. Why get I showed `NULL` and not the array?

**my console:** `Yay it worked ["1", "4"]`

**my javascript:**

```
    var values = [];

jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('.ui-btn').click(function() {
        values.push($(this).val());
        $.ajax({
            url: 'gamescreen.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                buttons: values,
            },
            success: function() {
               console.log('Yay it worked', values);
            },
            error: function() {
               console.log('Something went wrong');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**my html:**

```
 <div>
    <button name="btn1" type="submit" id="btn1" value="1" class="ui-btn"></button>
    <button name="btn2" type="submit" id="btn2" value="2" class="ui-btn"></button>
    </div> // I have up to 9 buttons, thats only a piece
```

**my php code:**

```
$buttons = $_POST['buttons'];
var_dump($buttons);
```

Comment: Are these buttons inside a form?

Comment: no they arent, I add the php snipped in a minute

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with php shown. How do you know it is not working ?

Comment: @Bodoppels your code is working and i do get the values also with $_POST['buttons'] : array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "2"
}

Comment: @charlietfl If I echo the array I get `NULL` and if I count it I get always `0`, too when I click any button the counted number wont changed. Is the ajax request responsible?

Comment: @Arsh, thanks for your attention to help. The log shows `Yay it worked ["3", "4", "2", "1", "1", "4"]` but if I count buttons it shows 0.

Comment: @Bodoppels by count what you mean this ? : count($buttons) ?

Comment: But where are you inspecting it? Have you tried returning array as json? Have you inspected the actual request in browser dev tools network?

Comment: @Arsh with `echo count($buttons);`

Comment: @Bodoppels even that is working fine for me  is your php code starting with : <?php   ????

Comment: @charlietfl I use chrome developer tool

Comment: Something is missing here then because `$_POST['buttons']` should work fine

Comment: @charlietfl it is working fine for me as well , i'm suspecting if his <?php open tag is there or not :/

Comment: `$_POST['buttons']``is in my php script after the jquery into the `</script>` tags. and after that I echo it in the body with php.

Comment: @Bodoppels but `$_POST['buttons']` only exists in the php during the ajax call. It does not persist. Also php only runs on the server. It sounds like maybe a misunderstanding about how ajax works

Comment: I get too `Undefined index: buttons`

Comment: Ok where should be my php?

Comment: Really not clear what you are trying to do. If you send that array to `gamescreen.php` what are you wanting to do with it?

Comment: First I want to echo it to look whether all works :D and after that I want to compare it with an other array :)

Comment: fine... can return it as json within ajax request but after that php knows nothing about it if you don't do anything else at server with that data

Comment: Oh, should I save it then anywhere?